# How long is the average time period of a senior/junior web developer in a company?

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, work-time

I like to know senior/junior web developers how long work in a company in average?

Or better to ask, how long they prefer/like to stay in a company? And what would be the main reason if they want to leave?

Answer (score 4):

> I like to know senior/junior web developers how long work in a company in average?

There is no ultimate answer to this question. They can be with a company for a time ranging from a few weeks to a life-time.

Usually, people stay with a company at least a few years before moving, as a rule of thumb.

There is even a trend claiming that jobs have to be changed every 2-3 years, but I know many people with 10+ years with the same company.

---

> And what would be the main reason if they want to leave?

Search on the net: "People join companies and leave managers."

---

> how long they prefer/like to stay in a company?

This question has the same answer regardless of the job. They stay as much as it is OK, and they do not have a better offer (e.g., from another company). Or they do not have a stronger incentive to move (e.g., to another country / city).

Answer (score 2):

**This is highly regional**

I'm in Calgary. My entire network is constantly changing jobs as there is a high demand for tech people and companies are fairly willing to hire and lay off. I worked an internship at a bank two summers ago and a fair number of people from that job are on their second position change (either internally or externally). It isn't a wear a suit everyday conservative bank, but it is still a bank, so it is not just a tech phenomenon.

They aren't drifting from failed startup to failed startup either. They aren't contractors. It is just how the market seems to work. Most people seem to make a move within 18 months. They either get a promotion at their current company or get it elsewhere.

In Silicon Valley, the [average tenure seems to be about 2 years.](https://mpstaff.com/the-ugly-truth-about-employee-turnover-in-silicon-valley/) People really do not last at companies like Amazon, where tenure is closer to 1.

Then you encounter the Europeans on here who think that 3 years is a short time to spend in a job or at a company.

Then I have met people from Vancouver who think that 8 months is a good time to start planning their next move.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Europeans prefer to spend 5-8 years at a company. They usually only quit if there are problems.